# Перегрузка операции инкремента

Tags: c++

Перегрузил операцию инкремента специально для своего класса, но возникла проблема: если написать `my_class++` то код не работает, зато при `++my_class` все выполняется правильно.

```
my_class &operator++(my_class &in)
{
}
```

Comment: так как этот оператор меняет  значение самого обьекта, лучше делать его членом класса

Comment: Вопрос не в этом. К тому же я не могу этого сделать, так как у меня нет доступа к изменению этого класса.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы перегрузили оператор преинкремента, он обычно выглядит так:

```
my_class& operator++(my_class &in)
{
    // какие-то инкрементирующие действия
    return in;
}
```

Этот оператор вызвается кодом:

```
my_class A;
++A;
```

Оператор постинкремента имеет вид:

```
my_class operator++(my_class &in, int dummy)
{
    my_class tmp = in;
    // Какие-то инкрементирующие действия
    return tmp;
}
```

Этот оператор вызвается кодом:

```
my_class A;
A++;
```

Обратите внимание на следующее:

1) Сигнатура оператора постинкремента имеет фиктивный аргумент `int`

2) Преинкремент возвращает ссылку на класс, который получился после инкрементирования

3) Постинкремент перед изменением `in` сохраняет его в временную переменную, чтобы потом вернуть его "до изменения" (и возвращает не ссылку, а копию).

Comment: Формально пункты 2 и 3 не являются обязательными. Мало ли какую семантику человек вкладывает в этот оператор :) Другое дело, что *не рекомендуется* использовать семантику, отличную от обычной семантики оператора, но не более того. Например, мне как-то встретился класс строки, в котором преинкрементный -- удалял пробельные символы в начале строки, а постинкрементный - в конце. Кстати, достаточно удобное решение :), но совершенно не вписывающееся в ваши правила...

Comment: есть такие примеры